# Should I connect an Oracle server to SQL Server or SQL Server to Oracle?

Tags: oracle11g, sql-server-2008-r2

We have a server with SQL Server 2008 R2 and one with Oracle 11g. Most of our queries occur on the same server as the SQL Server, but we have to do things like qoq and multiple loops to get matching data from oracle. In order to simplify some of the queries we do, I'd like to create a connection between the two.

Can I attach either one to either one?

Is there an advantage in either scenario? I realize the performance will vary depending on the rest of the environment, but does attaching one to the other generally work better or have an easier setup?

Comment: Well this question will draw a lot of opinions. Personally I'd go SQL Server --> Oracle since the majority of your code is sitting in SQL Server as you stated.

Comment: Can it be done either way?